# Javascript Regex to get table name from join sql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, regex

I have a query :

```
select a.id, a.nama, b.alamat from tsql as a join tswl as b on a.id = b.id join tscl as c on a.id=c.id
```

And using regex I wanted to get  **only**  the table name from the query string.

I tried using the regular expression :

```
select.*from\s+(\w+).*join\s(\w+).*
```

Which managed to get the first table name after "from", but skipped the second table name, and get the third table name. 

Current group :
[Group 1 : "tsql", Group 2 : "tscl"]

Targeted group :
[Group 1 : "tsql", Group 2 : "tswl", Group 3 : "tscl"] ... and so on until the last name of the chain join query

Any help will be apreciated!

Comment: You can't get 3 groups in the results since there are only 2 capturing groups in the regex. You need to match what you can and then split. Or, use optional groups, like [`select.*from\s+(\w+)(?:.*?join\s(\w+))?(?:.*?join\s(\w+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/ql8tsQ/1), you may repeat them as many times as you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current expression does not consider the possible repetition of the from/join keywords.

You could try this expression :

```
(?<=from|join)\s+(\w+)
```

Please try it yourself here : https://regex101.com/r/qQ1rvs/1

The positive lookbehind used here (?<=...) allows to capture any words (\w+) which are after it. In this case, every table names after these keywords are captured by this expression.

Answer (score 1):

Note:  The regexps discussed here will not work on most versions of MySQL because of the lame regexp parser.

Issues:

- White space
- `from` or `join` being used in a comment or string or column name, etc. (I won't tackle this.)
- Possible backtics around table name. -- handled, but with a bug
- Punctuation inside backtica -- not handled
- Possible setting that allows quotes around table name (not handled)
- Subqueries/`UNION` -- The table names will be lumped together without regard for such.
- Punctuation against from/join -- `FROM a JOIN(b JOIN c)` -- partially(?) Handled
- Derived table `FROM ( SELECT ... )` -- not handled
- Case (`from` vs `FROM`) -- outside the scipe of this regexp
- `LEFT OUTER JOIN` -- not a problem

So, this will mostly handle one table name:

```
\b(FROM|JOIN)\s+\`?(\w+)\`?
```

If JS has a way to iterate through a string, continuing where it left off, then you can get them all.

To better handle backtics and punctuation within:

```
\b(FROM|JOIN)\s+(\w+|`[^`]+`)
```

but you will need to strip the backtics when they occur.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var query = 'select a.id, a.nama, b.alamat from tsql as a join tswl as b on a.id = b.id join tscl as c on a.id=c.id';
console.log(query.match(/(from|join)\s+(\w+)/g).map(e => e.split(' ')[1]))
```

Output:

```
Array(3) [ "tsql", "tswl", "tscl" ]
```